# Python IndexError: Index out of bounds

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, indexing

This is part of my code:

```
print(part2QtlMtx[0][1][1])
for i in range(len(part2QtlMtx[0])):
    tmp = []
    for j in range(len(part2QtlMtx)):
        print(part2QtlMtx[0][1][1])
        tmp.append(part2QtlMtx[j][i][1])
```

And this is my output:

```
K_19
53.3
53.3
53.3
53.3
53.3
53.3
53.3
53.3
53.3
53.3
53.3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ExprM.py", line 55, in <module>
    quantile = qtl(mtx)
  File "ExprM.py", line 46, in qtl
    sortQtlMtx = sort(qtlMtx, len(mtx)-1, len(mtx[0]))
  File "ExprM.py", line 24, in sort
    print(part2QtlMtx[0][1][1])
IndexError: index out of bounds
```

I don't understand why it prints `print(part2QtlMtx[0][1][1])` as long as I'm not in the for-loop or before `i = 1` and `j = 0` just fine, but as soon as I get to i = 1 and j = 0, it tells me "Index out of bounds" for `print(part2QtlMtx[0][1][1])` even if worked until then.

I don't actually need the print part while I'm in the for-loop, but used it to figure out when the error occurs.

Comment: This is not possible to reproduce without showing us `part2QtlMtx`, I do wonder if the line number is not outputed correctly (ie the out of bounds error is actually on the append line)

Comment: @AndyH the part2QtlMtx is filled like this:

`[[(14886, 52.0), (7443, 53.3), (19865, 54.5), (5616, 55.3), (14991, 55.3), (10126, 55.5), (14294, 55.5), (7373, 55.8)], [(19617, 47.0), (19664, 47.8), (14490, 48.0), (14682, 48.0), (14886, 48.0), (4947, 48.3), (19865, 48.8), (16317, 49.0)], [(20200, 49.0), (19472, 49.3), (644, 49.5), (1032, 49.8), (15027, 49.8), (2517, 50.3), (6958, 50.3), (7257, 50.3)]]`

this is just a small bit of the full entry.

Comment: works ok with that example, perhaps you can pdb in (if you're using ipython then use %debug) to find out what all the variable are when the IndexError happens. Like I say, I suspect it's line numbering error (try deleting the .pyc file and see if the line number changes). Or perhaps easier, try printing j and i inside the for loop.

Comment: okay, i found my mistake, after this "j" for-loop there was another with the wrong indent for me (it still belonged to the "i" for loop, but didn't show, because it was the right syntax. i change something in part2QtlMtx, which doesn't seem to be compatible with those for-loops..

but thank you very much for your time and help :D